# How to make normal buttons in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: button, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I use an example code from the official site of python-telegram-bot module.
Here it is:
https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.conversationbot.html

This is what I get on the startphone:
https://imgur.com/a/5XzYKXo

And this is in the browser in the web telegram on PC:
There is only an icon that needs to be pressed so that buttons appear
I want the buttons were shown by default, without clicking this icon.
https://imgur.com/a/kZgUi93

How can I get buttons that look like this? Both on PC and phone
https://imgur.com/a/cVSgwpt

I'm expecting the buttons are shown above the text field by default, without clicking an icon.

Answer (score 0):

The first two pictures show a [`ReplyKeyboardMarkup`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.replykeyboardmarkup.html), while the third one shows an [`InlineKeyboardMarkup`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardmarkup.html). We provide an example for that [`here`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.7/examples.html#examples-inlinekeyboard)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.